# How are the older apps going to be displayed on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone

The new screen on the iPhone 5 has got a different ratio, 16:9 (1136:640). How are the older apps going to be displayed?

Comment: This must be like a duplicate of 5 other questions now.

Comment: Obviously I searched before posting it and didn’t find anything. I’m also a bit sorry about the downvotes, since I thought this to be a legitimate question interesting to all developers who have existing apps on the platform.

Comment: There are a number of people casting knee-jerk downvotes on iPhone 5 questions right now, possibly as a way of saying "it's just a little too early to ask". I didn't downvote any of the questions though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will be same size they are now fit in the center of the screen.

**EDIT** As of 2013-05-01 Apple requires all apps to support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must include a launch image of the appropriate size. Here is the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/TranslateApp/TranslateApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH10-SW8)

Comment: Sorry, couldnt resist. Is this now a form of fragmentation on the iOS side of things?

Comment: Quite possibly. But now you have more room for Ads ;-)

Answer (score 0):

They will be displayed in a letterbox.

Comment: Is there a source for this information anywhere?  I've been looking around but nothing pops out at me.

Comment: It just so happened that I had read about it on some site on the day the OP asked.  I was just browsing the tech. news, so I did not bookmark the site or anything - it was just a paragraph on some techie blog site - can't remember which one.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a little unused space on both sides.